# Why do I get an 'await is only valid in async functions' error when trying to fetch weather data using RapidAPI in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, urlfetch

```
const url =
  "https://weather-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/weather?city=delhi";
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "ce580959b4msh04ac7f304c1ee24p143e88jsncf6cf022f1d6",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "weather-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

try {
  const response  = await fetch(url, options);
  const result = await response.text();
  console.log(result);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

I was try to fetch weather API from rapidAPI
I just copyed the given code to fetch

Comment: Please [**search**](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+await+is+only+valid+in+async) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score -2):

This is because you are using `await` out of `async` scope.

Try to make the following change:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const response  = await fetch(url, options);
    const result = await response.text();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but two possible reasons are: 1) This is a common duplicate 2) Async IIFE is kind of outdated. Use modules.

Comment: 1) possibly 2) how can modules replace IIFE in the context above, where we need to check that `async` is a reason?

Comment: You don't need Async IIFE in a module. Modules allow top-level await. You can use modules in modern (7 years old) browsers and most other engines.

Comment: Right, but all of this has nothing to do with the snippet above, where we need to verify if `async` nature of context is a solution. I'm pretty sure that the code above (i.e. try-catch block) resides in some function too that can be made async (or the entire module will be async), but it is shown here without it for simplicity, and I used IIFE for simplicity too.

Comment: If this is a code inside a function, and your answer is to wrap it in a async IIFE, I would also downvote.